# Pandas DataFrame: append give index by name to end of df

Tags: pandas, append, dataframe, rows, reindex

I have df which looks like:

```
df_table
Name       exp1
bnb_q8a12    41
bnb_q8a8     36
bnb_q8a2     30
_xexp0       20
_xexp73      16
bnb_q8a7     10
_xexp216     10
bnb_q8a3     10
```

I would like the df to look like this, with all index which are named "Net: _xexp.." appended at the end of the df.

```
df_table
Name       exp1
bnb_q8a12         41
bnb_q8a8          36
bnb_q8a2          30
bnb_q8a7          10
bnb_q8a3          10
Net: _xexp0       20
Net: _xexp73      16
Net: _xexp216     10
```

I am current appending the given index like this but Im sure there is a better way of doing this?

```
res = df_table.index.tolist()
nets = []
for i in df_table.index:
    if 'Net: ' in i:
        nets.append(res.pop(res.index(i)))

res.extend(nets)
df_table = df_table.reindex(res)
```

Comment: So you want to prepend those rows and then shift them to end of the df? Also is this your index rather than your column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vectorised [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains) method to mask the df for the rows that contain the string and prepend the str. 
As it's currently your index, it's probably simpler to reset the index to restore it as a column, then filter the rows and prepend the text, use `concat` on the filtered rows to reorder them and then set the index back again:

```
In [64]:

df = df.reset_index()
df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('_xexp'), 'Name'] = 'Net: ' + df.Name
df
Out[64]:
            Name  exp1
0      bnb_q8a12    41
1       bnb_q8a8    36
2       bnb_q8a2    30
3    Net: _xexp0    20
4   Net: _xexp73    16
5       bnb_q8a7    10
6  Net: _xexp216    10
7       bnb_q8a3    10

In [65]:

df = pd.concat([df[~df.Name.str.contains('_xexp')], df[df.Name.str.contains('_xexp')]])
df
Out[65]:
            Name  exp1
0      bnb_q8a12    41
1       bnb_q8a8    36
2       bnb_q8a2    30
5       bnb_q8a7    10
7       bnb_q8a3    10
3    Net: _xexp0    20
4   Net: _xexp73    16
6  Net: _xexp216    10
In [66]:

df = df.set_index('Name')
df
Out[66]:
               exp1
Name               
bnb_q8a12        41
bnb_q8a8         36
bnb_q8a2         30
bnb_q8a7         10
bnb_q8a3         10
Net: _xexp0      20
Net: _xexp73     16
Net: _xexp216    10
```